# Draw a Octahedron

Tags: java, vector, graphics, 3d

So I am trying to draw a Octahedron, which I like 90% done, but one part of the object is not coloring properly. I think the issue in the int coords, I tried variety of numbers, but the part the still cut off.

```
import javax.vecmath.*; 

import javax.media.j3d.*;

public class Octahedron extends IndexedTriangleArray {
    public Octahedron(){
        super(8, TriangleArray.COORDINATES | TriangleArray.NORMALS, 24);
        setCoordinate(0, new Point3f(0f, 0f, 1f));
        setCoordinate(1, new Point3f(-1f, 0f, 0f));
        setCoordinate(2, new Point3f(0f, -1f, 0f));
        setCoordinate(3, new Point3f(1f, 0f, 0f));
        setCoordinate(4, new Point3f(0f, 1f, 0f));
        setCoordinate(5, new Point3f(0f, 0f, -1f));
        int[] coords = {3,0,5,0,2,5,2,0,4,0,3,4,5,1,3,2,1,5,4,1,2,3,1,4};
        float n = (float)(1.0/Math.sqrt(3));
        setNormal(0, new Vector3f(-n, -n, n));
        setNormal(1, new Vector3f(n, -n, n));
        setNormal(2, new Vector3f(n, n, n));
        setNormal(3, new Vector3f(-n, n, n));
        setNormal(4, new Vector3f(n, n, n));
        setNormal(5, new Vector3f(-n, n, n));
        setNormal(6, new Vector3f(-n, n, n));
        setNormal(7, new Vector3f(n, n, n));

        int[] norms = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7};
        setCoordinateIndices(0, coords);
        setNormalIndices(0, norms);

    }

}
import javax.vecmath.*;  
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.universe.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.geometry.*;
import java.applet.*;
import com.sun.j3d.utils.applet.MainFrame;

public class TestOctahedron extends Applet {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        new MainFrame(new TestOctahedron(), 640, 480);
        }

    public void init(){
        GraphicsConfiguration gc = SimpleUniverse.getPreferredConfiguration();
        Canvas3D cv = new Canvas3D(gc);
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(cv, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        BranchGroup bg = createSceneGraph();
        bg.compile();
        SimpleUniverse su = new SimpleUniverse(cv);
        su.getViewingPlatform().setNominalViewingTransform();
        su.addBranchGraph(bg);
    }

    private BranchGroup createSceneGraph() {
        BranchGroup root = new BranchGroup();
        TransformGroup spin = new TransformGroup();
        spin.setCapability(TransformGroup.ALLOW_TRANSFORM_WRITE);
        root.addChild(spin);
        Appearance ap = new Appearance();
        ap.setMaterial(new Material());
        Shape3D shape = new Shape3D(new Octahedron(), ap);
        Transform3D tr = new Transform3D();
        tr.setScale(0.25);
        TransformGroup tg = new TransformGroup(tr);
        spin.addChild(tg);
        tg.addChild(shape);
        Alpha alpha = new Alpha(-1, 4000);
        RotationInterpolator rotator = new RotationInterpolator(alpha, spin);
        BoundingSphere bounds = new BoundingSphere();
        rotator.setSchedulingBounds(bounds);
        spin.addChild(rotator);
        Background background = new Background(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        background.setApplicationBounds(bounds);
        root.addChild(background);
        AmbientLight light = new AmbientLight(true, new Color3f(Color.red));
        light.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        root.addChild(light);


        PointLight ptlight = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.green), new Point3f(3f, 3f, 3f), new Point3f(1f, 0f, 0f));
        ptlight.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        root.addChild(ptlight);
        PointLight ptlight2 = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.orange), new Point3f(-2f, 2f, 2f), new Point3f(1f, 0f, 0f));
        ptlight2.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
        root.addChild(ptlight2);
           PointLight ptlight3 = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.red),
                    new Point3f(2f,2f,-2f), new Point3f(1f,0f,0f));
                ptlight3.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
                root.addChild(ptlight3);
            PointLight ptlight4 = new PointLight(new Color3f(Color.blue),
                    new Point3f(-2f,-2f,-2f), new Point3f(1f,0f,0f));
                ptlight4.setInfluencingBounds(bounds);
                root.addChild(ptlight4);  
        return root;

    }

}
```

Comment: Make sure that all of your normals are pointing "outward". If that's not it, then you could try turning off culling.

Comment: can you briefly explain it.

Comment: You'll have to read up on backface culling and normals.  Essentially, what happens is if the polygon, surface, etc. is pointing away from the camera, the renderer will not do the work of coloring it because it's assumed that you can't see it.  So, without examining everything in your code, I recommend that you ensure that all of the normals are pointing away from the object.  Or you can take the shortcut of turning off the backface culling.  Here's an example: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/3D/TwistStripAppdemonstratesbackfaceculling.htm  

polyAttrib.setCullFace(PolygonAttributes.CULL_NONE);

Answer (score 0):

Is this the correct order

```
import javax.vecmath.*;
import javax.media.j3d.*;

public class Octahedron extends IndexedTriangleArray {
    
    public Octahedron() {
        super(8, TriangleArray.COORDINATES | TriangleArray.NORMALS, 24);
        this.setCoordinate(0, new Point3f(0f, 0f, 1f)); // A
        this.setCoordinate(1, new Point3f(-1f, 0f, 0f)); // B
        this.setCoordinate(2, new Point3f(0f, -1f, 0f)); // C
        this.setCoordinate(3, new Point3f(1f, 0f, 0f)); // D
        this.setCoordinate(4, new Point3f(0f, 1f, 0f)); // E
        this.setCoordinate(5, new Point3f(0f, 0f, -1f)); // F
        
        int[] coords = {0,1,2, 0,2,3, 0,3,4, 0,1,4, 5,1,2, 5,2,3, 5,3,4, 5,1,4, };
        float n = (float) (1.0 / Math.sqrt(3));
        
        this.setNormal(0, new Vector3f(-n, -n, n)); // ABC
        this.setNormal(1, new Vector3f(n, -n, n)); // ACD
        this.setNormal(2, new Vector3f(n, n, n)); // ADE
        this.setNormal(3, new Vector3f(-n, n, n)); // ABE
        this.setNormal(4, new Vector3f(-n, -n, -n)); // FBC
        this.setNormal(5, new Vector3f(n, -n, -n)); // FCD
        this.setNormal(6, new Vector3f(n, n, -n)); //FDE
        this.setNormal(7, new Vector3f(-n, n, -n)); //FBE
    
        int[] norms = {0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7};
        this.setCoordinateIndices(0, coords);
        this.setNormalIndices(0, norms);
    }
    
}
```